# I was trying to use a function from a different class in the main class, but i receive this: line 15, in MainMenu chosenOption.issuing_new_ticket()

Tags: python, class, methods

While building my project I wanted to be able to operate on different classes and objects, but when I was trying to use a function from a different class in the main class, but i receive this: line 15, in MainMenu chosenOption.issuing_new_ticket() and line 4, in  class MainMenu:.
I think it is because i am not creating my second class properly, how should i work around it ?

Here is my code:

```
class MainMenu:
    global chosenOption
    global ticketTitle
    global ticketDescribtion
    print("Welcome to Ticket Tracker")
    print("Main Menu")
    print("1 - Issue new Ticket")
    print("2 - Check Ticket Status")
    print("3 - Edit Ticket")
    print("4 - Exit")
    chosenOption = input("Enter your choice here: ")
    chosenOption.Options.issuing_new_ticket()


class Options:
    def issuing_new_ticket(self):
        if chosenOption == "1":
            print("Issuing new ticket in progress")
            ticket_title = input("Title of the ticket: ")
            ticket_describtion = input("Describe the issue/request: ")
```

Comment: I don't think you are using classes correctly. You may be able to get away with just using functions for your usecase: https://snipboard.io/mXP45R.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** `Option` class should be at the above of `MainMenu` class, otherwise it will show this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\apned\apneMailer\demo2.py", line 73, in <module>
    class MainMenu:
  File "c:\Users\apned\apneMailer\demo2.py", line 84, in MainMenu
    Options().issuing_new_ticket(chosenOption)
    ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'Options' is not defined
```

Because inside `MainMenu` class we call `Option` class which was not found by the python *as python runs from top to down*.

**Secondly,** you should not write :

```
chosenOption.Options.issuing_new_ticket()
```

As `Options` is not a strings's class in python. And, if you do this you will get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\apned\apneMailer\demo2.py", line 73, in <module>
    class MainMenu:
  File "c:\Users\apned\apneMailer\demo2.py", line 84, in MainMenu
    chosenOption.Options.issuing_new_ticket()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Options'
```

**What should you do now?**

Here is the working code...

```
class Options:
  def issuing_new_ticket(self, chosenOption):
    if chosenOption == "1":
      print("Issuing new ticket in progress")
      ticket_title = input("Title of the ticket: ")
      ticket_describtion = input("Describe the issue/request: ")
        
class MainMenu:
  global chosenOption
  global ticketTitle
  global ticketDescribtion
  print("Welcome to Ticket Tracker")
  print("Main Menu")
  print("1 - Issue new Ticket")
  print("2 - Check Ticket Status")
  print("3 - Edit Ticket")
  print("4 - Exit")
  chosenOption = input("Enter your choice here: ")
  Options().issuing_new_ticket(chosenOption) # calling Option's issuing_new_ticket() function

if __name__ == "__main__":
  MainMenu()
```